# Looking for a deep learning platform for image recognition, preferably in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, image-classification, deep-learning, tensorflow

As part of a project I am working on, I am collecting an image training dataset consisting of various images of agricultural fields (details spared for confidentiality). The end goal of the project is to build a convolutional neural network (CNN) that will be able to classify high-resolution aerial images based on the training images provided.

I am new to deep learning and CNNs, but I was wondering if there is a recommended QGIS (or other GIS) package that will allow orthomosaics images to be classified in this manner? I was hoping to use an IDE such as Tensorflow or PyTorch; is there a way to use these IDEs in conjunction with perhaps a QGIS deep learning plugin? Any recommendations? I'm just trying to get started in this area.

Comment: Orfeo toolbox should let you link TensorFlow to QGIS. See this [link](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/tag/machine-learning/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, QGIS have not developed a framework yet to integrate Deep Learning into the workflow as ArcGIS did (see here): https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/image-analyst/deep-learning-in-arcgis-pro.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_9A7FA576B255488DBDB6386DDF38C009

If you don't want to use ArcGIS you always can develop your Deep Learning Model without using any GIS tool at all. ArcGIS has put together under the same umbrella the different elements needed to carried out the task: data collection and labeling, training the model and inference exercise but still you need to understand the entire process. ArcGIS is just a tool which makes things a little bit easier and very limited so far so if you want to get started in Deep Learning I would recommend you to start from the basis and play around with tensorflow, Pytorch, train some small model, test it, etc.

Below are two very popular Guithub projects you can start with:

- https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN
- https://github.com/tensorpack/tensorpack

Comment: Great, I appreciate it! I may probably have to stick with ArcGIS, I was just trying to move to a more open-sourced program. It might even work for me to use ENVI, if I can get a hold of it.